# Extracting components and elements from a list, then merging them

Tags: r, list, sapply, cbind

I have made a list and want to pull out only certain components and elements of that list and save it as a data frame. However, when using the `sapply` function, it pulls the correct data for some elements, but for others it does not.

Here is a reproducible example:

#Creating an example list

```
library(KEGGREST)
chem_info <- keggGet(dbentries = c("C01546", "C05984"))
```

#Extracting what I need from the chem_info list. I am needing to extract the Compound, FORMULA, and PATHWAY fields. I have followed the directions listed here for parts of this step: [How to extract elements from a list with mixed elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662005/how-to-extract-elements-from-a-list-with-mixed-elements)

```
a <- as.list(t(sapply(chem_info, '[', c(1,3))))
b <- sapply(chem_info, '[[', 7)
cbind(a, Pathway = b)
```

#My Result & problem = there is a 'character, 3' instead of what the list has for the PATHWAY element of the list.

ENTRY    FORMULA  Pathway
[1,] "C01546" "C5H4O3" character,3
[2,] "C05984" "C4H8O3" "Propanoate metabolism"

What I am aiming for is to have everything listed under the PATHWAY elements for every entry to be listed under the pathway column. For example, the first entry, C01546 has 3 elements under PATHWAY, Furfural degradation, Metabolic pathways, and Microbial metabolism in diverse environments. I need this listed under the Pathway column. Here is an example output of what I'm hoping to achieve.

What I'm aiming for is the following:

ENTRY    FORMULA  Pathway
[1,] C01546 C5H4O3 Furfural degradation, Metabolic pathways, and Microbial metabolism in diverse environments
[2,] C05984 C4H8O3 "Propanoate metabolism"

Any help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This final line should do the trick. You just need to collapse any of the entries where it is a vector rather than a single element, before you can properly combine with `cbind()`.

```
cbind(a, Pathway = lapply(b, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ", ")))
```

```
     ENTRY    FORMULA  Pathway                                                                                 
[1,] "C01546" "C5H4O3" "Furfural degradation, Metabolic pathways, Microbial metabolism in diverse environments"
[2,] "C05984" "C4H8O3" "Propanoate metabolism"
```